# Largest submatrix of a given matrix, with swapping of rows/columns

Tags: matrices

If you have an $M \times N$ matrix with non-zero elements, find the largest sub-matrix that contains only non-zero elements.

The twist here is that you can swap any two rows, or any two columns, any number of times in order to maximize the answer. You cannot modify any of the elements though.

Comment: "Largest" in what sense?  Number of elements?

Comment: There is no "twist": swapping rows, or swapping columns, doesn't change the answer, it just rearranges it.

Comment: Largest as in the number of elements in the sub matrix.

Swapping does change the answer. Consider a 4x4 matrix where the elements in the first and last row, and first and last column are non-zero, rest are zero. Largest sub-matrix is of size 4x1. Now if we swap the last column with the second column, the largest submatrix is of size 4x2. Thus, being able to swap two rows/cols changes the answer.

Comment: It depends on whether you consider "submatrix" to imply consecutive rows and columns.  I would say that before swapping the submatrix consisting of the first and last rows is still $4 \times 2$.

Comment: The usual definition of "submatrix" allows any subset of the rows and any subset of the columns.  See e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_%28mathematics%29#Submatrix).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a binary quadratic programming formulation.

Let $x_i = 1$ if row $i$ is to be included, $0$ otherwise, similarly $y_j$ for column $j$.

maximize $\sum_i \sum_j x_i y_j$

subject to:

$x_i + y_j \le 1$ for each pair $(i,j)$ such that the element $a_{ij}$ of your matrix is $0$,

all $x_i$ and $y_j$ in $\{0,1\}$.

You can make it into binary linear programming problems: for each $n$ up to the number of columns, maximize $n \sum_i x_i$ with those constraints plus $\sum_j y_j = n$, and take the maximum of the objective values for different $n$.

I think the problem is difficult, though.  Consider the adjacency matrix $A$ of a graph $G$.  There is an $m \times n$ submatrix of $A$ with all nonzero elements iff $G$ has a subgraph isomorphic to the complete bipartite graph $K_{m,n}$.  Subgraph isomorphism in general is NP-complete.

Comment: I have a similar problem.  But for this problem, how would one verify a solution to be correct?  (Since you said it's NP-complete, I assume it's possible to verify in polynomial time).  Maybe I should start a new thread.  :)